# does NLB forward to ALB even if the target group health check fails?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

My ALB configuration is as follows

- When the traffic goes from to ALB directly everything is fine and the website is working

```sh
HTTP 80
HTTPS 444
```

My NLB configuration is as follows

- For the NLB the target group is the ALB itself

[image]
[image]

As you can see the health-check is failing.

Now the http target group
[image]

[image]

Now this target group is healthy.

Also the network loadbalancer configuration is set up as follows

```sh
TCP 80
TCP 443
```

Strangely my website is working on both http and https.
So does this mean that the NLB forwards the request to ALB irrespective of the fact whether the healthcheck is passing or not ?

Answer (score 1):

My assumption is its working because of the following

> If a target group contains only unhealthy registered targets, the load balancer routes requests to all those targets, regardless of their health status.This means that if all targets fail health checks at the same time in all enabled Availability Zones, the load balancer fails open. The effect of the fail-open is to allow traffic to all targets in all enabled Availability Zones, regardless of their health status, based on the load balancing algorithm.

[target-group-health-checks.html](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/target-group-health-checks.html)

The same must be followed by NLB as well.